# Identify and/or clear alarm on Sunfire X4200 via ILOM

Tags: sun, lom

I've got a customer with a remotely-hosted X4200 and all they know is that there is an amber alarm light on the front of the server.  I've been asked to identify the offending component (if any) and clear the alarm if it's nothing to worry about.  The box is no longer under support.  It's running RHEL 4.x but no IMPI tools are installed (nor will I be allowed to install them).

My experience with Sun servers pre-dates the introduction of the ILOM, and I've had trouble finding useful documentation (yes, including Sun's) to get me started.

Running

```
show /SYS
```

doesn't yield any alarms (all properties are `(none)`).

Any pointers on how to chase this down would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
show faulty
```

It will list all the faults that lit amber LED as described in [this particular post](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19910-01/E21500-01/z40000091396897.html) on the Oracle/Sun site.

Comment: Note to anyone who finds this: It doesn't work on a 4100/4200 -> `show: No such target /SP/faultmgmt`